# Perl Net::SSLeay check if socket is available to read

Tags: perl, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am using a perl module called Net::APNS::Persistent. It helps me to open up a persistent connection with apple's [apns server](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) and send push notifications through APNS. This module uses Net::SSLeay for ssl communication with APNS server.

Now, I want to read from my socket periodically to check if APNS sends back any response. Net::APNS::Persistent already has a function called _read() which looks like below:

```
sub _read {
    my $self = shift;

    my ($socket, $ctx, $ssl) = @{$self->_connection};

    my $data = Net::SSLeay::ssl_read_all( $ssl );
    die_if_ssl_error("error reading from ssl connection: $!");

    return $data;
}
```

However, this function works only after APNS drops the connection and I get error while trying to write. On other times my script gets stuck at,

```
my $data = Net::SSLeay::ssl_read_all( $ssl );
```

I checked Net::SSLeay doc and found it has a method called peek

> Copies $max bytes from the specified $ssl into the returned value. In contrast to the Net::SSLeay::read() function, the data in the SSL buffer is unmodified after the SSL_peek() operation.

I though it might be useful, so I added another function within the Net::APNS::Persistent module:

```
sub ssl_peek {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($socket, $ctx, $ssl) = @{$self->_connection};
    print "Peeking \n";
    my $data = Net::SSLeay::peek( $ssl, $pending );
    print "Done peeking \n";
    return $data;
}
```

Unfortunately this also gave me the same problem. It only prints Peeking and never reaches the line where it would print Done peeking. Had same problem using Net::SSLeay::read. Is there a way to check if the socket can be read or maybe set a read timeout so that my script doesnt get stuck while trying to read from socket?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve by peeking into the socket? Do you expect some response from APNS?

Functions that are prefixed by underscore (_) are not supposed to be part of the module's interface, so you should not use them in an ideal case.

Comment: Yes I am trying to see if APNS is sending back any response. Please ignore the underscore. I am calling this function internally from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) says the following:

> If you send a notification that is accepted by APNs, nothing is returned.
>
> If you send a notification that is malformed or otherwise unintelligible, APNs returns an error-response packet and closes the connection. Any notifications that you sent after the malformed notification using the same connection are discarded, and must be resent

As long as your notifications as accepted, there won't be any data to read and thus a read operation on the socket will block. The only time there's data available is when there's an error, and then the connection is immediately closed. That should explain the behaviour you're observing.

Comment: So theres no point of reading the socket before the connection is closed. Thanks a lot... that answered my question. can you please take a look at my other thread also. Hope you have some answers for them aswell. Thanks in advanced! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004501/how-does-apns-behave-when-notification-is-sent-to-a-token-that-failed-before

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I looked at your other question but unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough about APNs to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the underlying socket can be read use select, i.e.

```
 IO::Select->new(fileno($socket))->can_read(timeout);
```

timeout can be `0` to just check and not wait, can be a number of seconds or can be `undef` to wait forever. But before you do the select check if data are still available in the SSL buffer:

```
 if (Net::SSLeay::pending($ssl)) { ... use SSL_peek or SSL_read ... }
```

Apart from that it does look like that the module you use does not even attempt to validate the servers certificate :(

Comment: thanks for our reply. I actually tried Net::SSLeay::pending aswell. It gives me 0 all the time. Even when I can read something from the socket(once connection is dropped). Any idea why?

Comment: @user3360140: pending checks only if there are unread data in the local SSL buffer. It does not try to read from the network. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_pending.html